# Homomorphism of $R$-modules gives a commutative diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

I am working on Problem 2.10 of Atiyah & Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*.

In this problem, we have a commutative ring $A$ and a homomorphism $u : M \longrightarrow N$ of $A$-modules.

Let $a$ be an ideal of $R$. In the solution [here](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ejtaylor/notes/atiyah_macdonald_solutions.pdf), they claim that the following diagram is commutative :

[image]

It's clear that $u$ induces the quotient map $w$ and the restriction map $v$, but it's unclear to me how the author makes the claim that the diagram is commutative fairly quickly. How can I see this ?

Note : It is given that $N$ is finitely generated. It is also given that $a$ is an ideal contained in the Jacobson radical of $A$. However, I don't think that either of these assumptions affect the claim being made here.

Thanks!

Comment: You say that $v$ is the restriction (strictly speaking, is the restriction with a restricted codomain) and that $w$ is the induced map of $u$ on the quotients. Doesn't that exactly mean that the diagram is commutative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi : M \to M'$ be a module homomorphism, and let $N$ and $N'$ be submodules of $M$ and $M'$, respectively. If $\varphi(N) \subseteq N'$, then we can define two new homomorphisms:

- The *restriction* of $\varphi$ on $N$, namely the map $\tilde\varphi : N \to N'$ that sends $n$ to $\varphi(n)$. Indeed, if $i : N \to M$ and $i' : N' \to M'$ are the inclusions, the true restriction of $\varphi$ on $N$ is the map $\varphi \circ i : N \to M'$, which is the same as $i' \circ \tilde\varphi$ (that is, $\tilde\varphi$ with extended codomain). In other words, $\tilde\varphi : N \to N'$ is the unique map that makes the diagram
  $$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
  N @>{\tilde\varphi}>> N' \\
  @V{i}VV @VV{i'}V \\
  M @>>{\varphi}> M'
  \end{CD}
  $$
  commutative.
- The *induced* map of $\varphi$ on the quotients, namely the map $\overline \varphi : M/N \to M'/N'$ that sends $m+N$ to $\varphi(m)+N'$. This is well-defined, for if $m_1+N=m_2+N$, then $m_1-m_2 \in N$ and then $\varphi(m_1)-\varphi(m_2) = \varphi(m_1-m_2) \in \varphi(N) \subseteq N'$, which means $\varphi(m_1)+N'=\varphi(m_2)+N'$. Now, if $\pi : M \to M/N$ and $\pi' : M' \to M'/N'$ are the canonical projections, we observe that $$\pi'(\varphi(m)) = \varphi(m)+N' = \overline\varphi(m+N) = \overline\varphi(\pi(m))$$ for all $m \in M$, in other words, $\overline \varphi : M/N \to M'/N'$ is the unique map that makes the diagram
  $$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
  M @>{\varphi}>> M' \\
  @V{\pi}VV @VV{\pi'}V \\
  M/N @>>{\overline\varphi}> M'/N'
  \end{CD}
  $$
  commutative.

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks ! Not sure why you were originally downvoted.

Comment: @michiganbiker898 I'm glad it helped you! I can't explain why the downvote either.

Comment: There was a "drive-by downvoter" last night who downvoted a batch of stuff. Have another upvote to make up for it.

Answer (score 2):

The practical answer is a brief chase of elements through the diagram. The abstract nonsense answer is also quick. Consider:

[image: quotients]

On the left, $d$ is defined to be the composite of the left and bottom maps. On the right, the universal property of quotients says there exists a unique $w$ which makes the triangle commute. Obviously that requires a check: you must show $d(\mathfrak{a}M) = 0$, or equivalently $u(\mathfrak{a}M) \subset \mathfrak{a}N$, which is clear. Saying both triangles commute is precisely saying the square commutes.