# Commutative square inducing a linear transformation $r:\text{Coker }b\to \text{Coker }c.$

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence, morphism

The following is based on an exercise from the book $linear algebra and geometry" by Leung.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

Given the linear transformation $c:X\to Y$ and the commutative square diagram below also with linear transformations $b,c,d.$

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X  \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c   \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y \\
\end{array},\quad (1)$$

Show that the linear transformations $a,d$ define a linear transformation $\text{Coker }b  \to  \text{Coker }c$

Attempted solution:

> From the diagram above, I am given $a\cdot c=b\cdot d,$  I then extend the square diagram like below.
>
> $$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X \\
> b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c  \\
> Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y  \\
> q'\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow q  \\
> Y'/\text{Im }b & \xrightarrow{r} & Y/\text{Im }c \\
> \end{array}\quad\quad (2)$$
>
> I think I need to show $r(\text{Coker }b)  \subset  \text{Coker }c,$  in order to show  $\text{Coker }b  \to  \text{Coker }c.$  Elements of $\text{Coker }b$ and $\text{Coker }c$ are respectively $y'+ \text{Im }b$ and   $y+\text{Im }c.$  It is easy to show that the linear transformation $r(\text{Coker }b)$ is well defined.  So let $x'\in X',$ then $(c\cdot a)(x')=(d\cdot b)(x')$
>
> $\Longrightarrow c(a(x'))=d(b(x')),$
>
> $\Longrightarrow c(x)=d(y'),$
>
> But $(r\cdot q')(y')=(q\cdot d)(y')$
>
> $\Longrightarrow r(q'(y'))=q(d(y')),$
>
> and $q'(y')=y'+\text{Im }b\Longrightarrow r(y'+\text{Im }b)=y+\text{Im }c$
>
> Also, $q(d(y'))=q(c(x))=q(y)=y+\text{Im }c$
>
> Hence $r(y'+\text{Im }b)=q(y)=y+\text{Im }c,$ which implies $r(\text{Coker }b)  \subset  \text{Coker }c.$  So the linear transformation we are looking for is $r:\text{Coker }b\to \text{Coker }c.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I posted the above exercise [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788307/how-to-define-linear-transformations-textker-b-to-textker-c-texti) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790209/defining-linear-transformation-r-textcoker-b-to-textcoker-c-given-a-c).  In both posts, I don't understand from the commenters how to go about fixing the solution to my post.  I think from the second post, Osama Ghani adviced me that I can define $$ by looking at a preimage of something in coker $$ in $′$ and then applying $\cdot.$ Is this what he meant?

Let $^{−1}(\{y+\text{Im }b\})=′,$ be the inverse image of $q',$ then $(q'\cdot z^{-1})(\{y+\text{Im }b\})=(q'(z^{-1}(\{y'+\text{Im }b\}))=q'(y').$  Hence $r\cdot (q'\cdot z^{-1})(\{y+\text{Im }b\})=r(q'(y'))=q(d(y'))\Longrightarrow r(y+\text{Im }b)=q(d(y'))=q(c(x))=q(y)=y+\text{Im }c.$

If the above is not what he meant, can someone showm me how to correctly go about showing that the commutative square above can induce a linear transformation $r:\text{Coker }b\to \text{Coker }c.$

Thank you in advance

Comment: $r:coker b \rightarrow coker c$ by $y'+im b \rightarrow d(y')+im c$. First, It is enough to prove that $r$ is well-defined and a linear transformation. It is easy as you said. Then we get the result.

Comment: @Well I also look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040442/homomorphism-of-r-modules-gives-a-commutative-diagram), from azif00's answer, do I have to do something similar,the way he did in the portion where he states the other induced homomorphism is "the *induced* map of $\varphi$ on the quotients."   Instead of $\varphi,$ I do it for $d:Y'\to Y.$ I don't have $a(X')\subset X,$ but I do have $b(X')\subset Y'$ and $c(X)\subset Y,$ and $\text{Im }b=b(X'),$ and $\text{Im }c=c(X).$  Also, don't I have to use the commutativity of the square to show the existence of $r$?

Comment: $a$ is a fixed linear transformation, then $a(X')\subset X$. And in fact $r$ only depends on $d$ by our definition. The commutativity of the square guarantees  that $r$ is well defined:$y'_1 +im b = y'_2+ im b \Rightarrow y'_1-y'_2 \in im b \Rightarrow \exists x\in X'$ such that $b(x)=y'_1-y'_2$,then $c(a(x))=d(b(x))=d(y'_1-y'_2)=d(y'_1)-d(y'_2)$,so $d(y'_1) + im  c = d(y'_2) + im c$.

Comment: @Well I just saw your answer now.  Thank you for the clarification.  I wasn't sure if and when I can use $a(X')\subset X.$  one minor question, do I need to assume that $b(X')\subset Y',$ and $c(X)\subset Y',$ in my argument?

Comment: if $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a map, then  $f(A) \subset B$ is trivial. This is just a basic condition such that the map is well defined. And in your argument, these are not used.

Comment: @Well what does $f(A)\subset B$ is trivial mean?  Also, that basic condition, does it matter whether that is used or not? The reason I am asking this is because there are four linear transformations in the commutative square, $a,d$ and the pair $b,c.$  Since there are maps $q':Y'\to Y'/\text{Im }b$ and $q:Y\to Y/\text{Im }c.$  Would it make sense to have the pair of restrictions map $b(X')\subset Y'$ and $c(X)\subset Y,$ instead of $a(X')\subset X.$  Also, in the other post I refered to,@Well what does $f(A)\subset B$ is trivial mean?  Also, that basic condition,...

Comment: @Well...  does it matter whether that is used or not? The reason I am asking this is because there are four linear transformations in the commutative square, $a,d$ and the pair $b,c.$  Since there are maps $q':Y'\to Y'/\text{Im }b$ and $q:Y\to Y/\text{Im }c.$  Would it make sense to have the pair of restrictions map $b(X')\subset Y'$ and $c(X)\subset Y,$ instead of azif00's answer had restriction $\varphi:(N)\to N'$ for the map $\varphi:M\to M',$ $M'\subset M, N'\subset N,$ both $M',N'$ are submodules.  It would make sense to have $b(X')\subset X, c(Y')\subset Y$ instead of $a(X')\subset X.$

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your idea. I think that  my previous proof had stated my idea. I don't know why you consider $b(X')\subset X,c(X)\subset Y$ all the time.  Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Well I want to know if I have a map $c:X\to Y$, in the context of my post.  In addition to three other linear transformation making a commutative square.  If I want to define a linear transformation $r:\text{Coker }b\to \text{Coker }c,$ based on two of the four linear transformations, $b,c$.  Does it matter I have the restrictions for each of the two linear transforamtions used to define the map $r$ to have restricted maps of the form $f(A)\subset B?$  If so, do these restricted maps have to come from the linear transformations that are used to definje the map $r?$?

Comment: You don't need to restrict the two linear transformation.

Comment: @Well by the way what did you meant by $f(A)\subset B$ is trivial?  I am guessing from your answer that azif00's answer in the other post [Homomorphism of $R$-modules gives a commutative diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040442/homomorphism-of-r-modules-gives-a-commutative-diagram) is not relevant?

Comment: @Well Also thank you so much for taking the time out to answer all of my questions.   Sorry if our interaction seems to be a bit convoluted at times.  I am learning this stuff on my own, I have a lot of questions about this stuff that are not covered in texts that I am using.